# solve 2nd order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + a\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} +bu = f(x,y)
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $b>a>0$.

Also $\space u(x,0) = g(x)$, and $\space u(0,y) = h(y)$

How do i approach such a problem? I tried finding C.F. by separation of variables technique but got stuck on deciding the value of separation parameter. And how do i find the P.I.?

Comment: What does "C.F." mean$

Comment: CF: complementary function

Comment: You haven't got enough boundary conditions.

Comment: @Mattos I am simply asking for hints, resources on solving specifically the above mentioned type of PDE. I went through lot of resources but couldn't find one

Comment: You can assume your own $f(x,y)$ and boundary conditions and show how to deal with such PDE

Comment: What's the domain for $x,y$?

Comment: @Skip both are real and $x,y \geq 0$

Comment: We can consider $x$ as some length element and bound it as $0 \leq x \leq L$ and $y$ as some time element

Comment: The substitution $y= \sqrt{a}s$ reduces the equation to the [inhomogeneous Hemholtz's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation) $\nabla^2u + k^2u = f$. Then you solve it using Green's function

Comment: @Dylan seems very complicated, can you show me an actual solved example

Comment: i found [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2012.03.014) but very hard to understand, also the $k^2 u$ term is in RHS

Comment: @Dylan why did you put down your answer? i was in the middle of using it. i also found [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0307904X84900519?via%3Dihub)

Comment: The answer is back. I first deleted it when I thought the method wasn't as accessible as. say. the Fourier or Laplace transforms. I didn't have much luck with them though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the substitution $y = \sqrt{a} \cdot \bar{y}$ to obtain the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation

\begin{cases} \nabla^2 u + k^2 u = f, & (x,\bar y) \in D \\ u = g, & y=0 \\ u = h, & x = 0 \end{cases}

where $D$ is the quarter plane $\{x > 0, \bar y > 0\}$ on $\Bbb R^2$

We can use the same method used for the Laplace equation [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/greensfn.pdf), with some modifications.

---

**Step 1.** Find the Green's function $G(x,x',\bar y,\bar y')$ on an open domain  such that

$$ (\nabla^2 + k^2)G = \delta(x-x',\bar y-\bar y'), \quad (x',\bar y') \in \Bbb R^2 $$

There are several options, the most common one you'll find is

$$ G(\rho) = \frac{i}{4}[J_0(k\rho) + iY_0(k\rho)], \quad \rho = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(\bar y-\bar y')^2} $$

where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are Bessel functions. The real part of this function, with just $Y_0$, would also work here.

---

**Step 2.** Find the Green's function on the desired domain. We want $G_D(x,x',\bar y,\bar y')$ such that

\begin{cases}
(\nabla^2 + k^2)G_D = \delta(\rho), & (x',\bar y') \in D \\
G = 0, & \bar y' = 0 \\
G = 0, & x' = 0
\end{cases}

Using the method of images, we find

$$ G_D(x,x',\bar y, \bar y') = \frac14 \big[G(x,x',\bar y,\bar y') - G(x,x',\bar y,-\bar y') - G(x,-x',\bar y, \bar y') + G(x,-x',\bar y,-\bar y')\big] $$

---

**Step 3.** Integrate the Green's function. Using [Green's second identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_second_identity)

\begin{align}
\iint_D \big[u(\mathbf{r}')\cdot(\nabla^2+k^2)G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}') - G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')\cdot (\nabla^2+k^2)u(\mathbf{r}') \big]dA' &= \int_{\partial D} \big[u(\mathbf{r}')\nabla G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}') - G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})\nabla u(\mathbf{r})\big]\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}ds' \\
u(\mathbf{r}) - \iint_D G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')f(\mathbf{r}') dA' &= \int_{\partial D} u(\mathbf{r}')\nabla G_D(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')\cdot \mathbf{n} ds' 
\end{align}

$$ \implies u(x,\bar y) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty G_Df(x',\bar y')dx' d\bar y' + \int_0^\infty g(x') \frac{\partial G_D}{\partial \bar y'}\Bigg\vert_{y'=0}dx' + \int_0^\infty h(y') \frac{\partial G_D}{\partial x'}\Bigg\vert_{x'=0} dy' $$

Note that this doesn't guarantee a unique solution, since there exists a family of homogeneous solutions

$$ u_h(x,y) = \sin(k_x x)\sin(k_y y), \quad k_x^2 + k_y^2 = k^2 $$

such that if $u(x,y)$ is a solution, then $u(x,y) + Cu_h(x,y)$ is also a solution.